# Delete repeated ids from a table in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the following structure in BigQuery:

```sql
CREATE TABLE if not EXISTS tbl (
  id_1 int,
  id_2 int,
  value int
);

INSERT INTO tbl values
(1, 1, 0),
(1, 1, 0.1),
(1, 2, 0),
(1, 2, 0),
(2, 1, 0),
(2, 2, 0.1),
(2, 2, 0.5),
(2, 2, 0.9);
```

I want to delete repeated rows using the following logic:

- I want to have only 1 row by `id_1`, `id_2` pair.
- I want to keep the row with the highest value.

Under the following conditions:

- There may be ties but I only want to keep 1 of the tie.
- For a given id pair, there may be 1, 2 or more rows for that id pair.

In this specific case, the output table should be:

```
id_1,id_2,value
1, 1, 0.1
1, 2, 0
2, 1, 0
2, 2, 0.9
```

What's the simplest way of doing this `delete` in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
create or replace table `project.dataset.table` as 
select array_agg(t order by value desc limit 1)[offset(0)].*
from `project.dataset.table` t
group by t.id_1, t.id_2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a query that returns the results, then use:

```
select t.*
from t
where 1=1
qualify row_number() over (partition by id_1, id_2 order by value desc);
```

Unfortunately, if you want to delete rows in the table, the complete duplicates cause a problem.  I would instead suggest that you save the results of the above query into a table.

Comment: So, is it not possible to solve this with a delete?

Comment: @DavidMasip . . . Not unless you have another query that can distinguish between otherwise identical rows.  I mean, you could add such a column, provide a value, and then use `delete`, but replacing the table is simpler.